# How do I increase the spacing between different parts of blockquotes with CSS?

Tags: html, css, blockquote

I have a bunch of nested quotes I want to display, but I find (see the attached example below) that the spacing between quotes is too small. How do I increase this?

HTML:

```
<blockquote>stuff
  <blockquote>neato</blockquote>
</blockquote>
```

CSS:

```
blockquote {
    border-left: 1.5px solid #ccc;
    color: #888;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 12px;
}
```

Here's an interactive example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bNKZVo?editors=110

In that example I find the spacing under "neat" and the next quote is too tight and I'd like more room. I tried `line-height`, but while the spacing between them eventually gets better, (around 50 line height) it makes the second quote of an absurd height.

Comment: `padding: 12px 0 0 12px;` perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add margin top to nested bloquote do exactly that, in CSS you can express that as:

```
blockquote blockquote {margin-top:10px}
```

This way there is no margin on the top level bloquote, but all the nested do get it.

Comment: OP might need that to be padding.  There's a left border in the example.

Answer (score 0):

What about a new CSS block:

```
blockquote > blockquote {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

That will affect only the nested quotes, and not the top-level one.

Comment: NOTE: this will only affect direct children